# Cant call a function from another script

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I have a script called Ball, from within that script I am trying to call a function from another script called Bricks.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
    Bricks bricks = GetComponent<Bricks> ();
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Paddle") {
        print("hit");
        bricks.MoveDown ();

    }
```

Now I know that this if statement becomes true as "hit" is printed, however it does not execute the function below. Any ideas? Thanks

```
public void MoveDown(){
    print ("test");
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position ,transform.position + amountToMove, 1);
}
```

Comment: Vector3.Lerp must be called within the Update() or LateUpdate() function.

Comment: I don't get as far as calling the Lerp, I can't even get "test" to print. And if I were to put this in an update function how would I only be able to call it on a collision event?

Comment: Does the "Bricks" component reside on the same gameobject? And to do something like that on a collision event you would need to flag a boolean on the collision and then in the scripts update function `if(bool == true){ //Do Lerp }`

Comment: Also, [`CompareTag()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

Comment: I have a feeling you want to call that function on the object you just collided with. If so, use `other.transform. GetComponent<Bricks>()` to get the script then call the function. If not seethe duplicate which explains how to do this

Comment: @Programmer The object he's colliding with is the paddle. Refer to his if statement. I'm assuming this is a "Breakout" clone. He may need to actually FIND the gameobject that has the "Bricks" component. But, then again, if the Bricks script didn't reside on the Ball gameobject, wouldn't there be a Null Reference exception when calling MoveDown()?

Comment: I don't know what OP is doing or where which script is attach but the duplicate shows how to call another function in another script.